# Check if for username and password the type is for a client or for a administrator

Tags: c#, sql, database

I just finished a database in C# with SQL. In my database I add data when I create the account for a person. I add the username, password, first and last name and the type (client or administrator).

When I am logging in all what I do is to check if username and password are correct. Here is the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MARIA-PC;Initial Catalog=Account;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Cont] WHERE Username = @Username and Password = @Password;", con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.Username.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", this.Password.Text);
        cmd1.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();

        bool loginSuccessful = ((ds.Tables.Count > 0) && (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0));

        if (loginSuccessful )
        {
                MessageBox.Show("You logged in successfully!","Success!");
                this.Visible = false;
                f3.ShowDialog();
                this.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!", "Error!");
        }

    }
```

And next what I want to do is to check if for this username and password the type is for client or administrator. And if is for administrator to entry in a form or if is for client to entry in another form.

How can I do? I need some ideas.

Here is the table: 
[image]

Comment: You are retrieving the full row, so there is no problem in reading the column that contains the type administrator or client. How is called this column and what is its datatype?

Comment: few questions for clarifications: 1. how the user inputs type? 2. is type is a field in the database? if so what's the difficulty to add another condition to the where clause?

Comment: Are you storing passwords in plain text? Because that's a Very Bad Thing. Salt and hash, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving the full row from your database table, so you have also retrieved the column that contains the usertype. You just need to check it after verifying the login

Here an example assuming that a "1" value means administrator, a "2" means normal user (of course you could change these constants to your actual values)

```
   if (loginSuccessful )
   {
       string userType = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Type"].ToString();
       if(userType == "1")
       {
           // User is an administrator, go to admin form
       }
       else if(userType == "2") 
       {
           // User is a normal user, go to user form
       }
       else
       {
           // Unexpected value, error message?
       } 
   }
```

A side note, while you are using parameters there is still a security problem in your database/code logic. It seems that you store your password as a plain text. This could give to anyone that looks at your database table the possibility to know your users passwords. A password should never be stored in plain text. This site contains a lot of answer on how to correctly store passwords in a database

Start from here:

[Best way to store passwords in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

Comment: I will look there to read about it and to apply. I'm a begginer and I need this for school and I don't know what is good or not for a programme like this. But thank you for your observations

Comment: At `int userType = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserType"]);` I have this error `Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: As I have said, the example supposes that you have an integer column for the Type field. Now it is clear that this is not the case. What values do you have there to recognize a user as an administrator instead of a normal user?

Comment: When I create account I ask if is administrator or is a normal user and in database appear Administrator or Client

Comment: Answer updated, for the password problem you could let pass it now or try to implement the hashing algorithm if you want to impress your teacher but remember this point if, by chance or by choiche, you need to write code for a living

Comment: @MariaD you could look at the column Type values and change the above code accordingly

Comment: And how can I change it?

Comment: @MariaD could you look at that table using the server explorer window or just the Sql Server Management Studio? Look at the value present in the column Type and change "1" with the value stored in the type column for an Administrator user and change "2" with the value stored for the normal user.

Comment: I find and now is functioning. Thank you. :)